# grid__item sizing simply not working?

Tags: css, responsive-design, shopify

I'm trying to do something fairly simple that I've done many times and I have no idea why it isn't working.

The following is simplified code for what I'm trying to do:

```
  <div class="grid grid--uniform new-header">
    <div class="grid__item small-up--one-third">  

      some stuff
    </div>

    <div class="grid__item small-up--one-third">  
         some stuff
    </div>


     <div class="grid__item small-up--one-third">  
      some stuff
    </div>

  </div>
```

No matter what I put as the second class after grid__item, I cannot get it to become any fraction of the size of the page. Currently, all divs are full-width regardless of me directing them to be one third.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a css question than a liquid one. Correct me if I am wrong; I think your code relates mostly to [Timber](https://shopify.github.io/Timber/#grid).

Timber is mobile first so you don't have to do `small-up` what you want is more like `small--one-third`. If the grid item is only going to be one third you can simply do: `grid__item one-third`